# Single stage under counter water filter

Tags: water, filter

I'll say that this may be somewhat of a physics question.
On my GE Model # GX1S01R the intake hose (from the water supply) and the output hose (to sink water dispenser) are both at the top of the filter housing (I think is is called the sump housing). The filter sits loosely inside the housing. I always wondered if the water flowed in above the filter and out the other side. How do I know if it is actually being circulated through the filter? Yes, the old filter brown and the new one is white, but, is the water actually being drawn through the filter, or is the filter just sitting in a housing of tap water?

[image: GE water filter]

Answer (score 1):

When you change the filter next, have a look at the internal paths for the inlet and outlet - they are designed to control the flow through the filter, normally flow is outside to middle.

Answer (score 0):

They are designed to push the water through the filter.  it flows through the filter.

The water enters the chamber on the outside of the filter, the outlet receives water from the inside of the filter. The water pressure pushes the water though the filter and out the outlet, I.E. from outside to inside filtering the water.

> How do I know if it is actually being circulated through the filter?

Once the filter housing is screwed on it creates a seal so water has to flow through the filter.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad someone knows how it works :)